# How to create a Grafana alert when a prometheus gauge value doesn't change for a long time?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I have a custom **gauge** metric (say, `my-custom-metric`) that I created using Prometheus client in my backend. This metric's value is updated periodically using a cron job. It represents the number of operations (of a specific type) performed by the backend i.e. the value of metric always increases.

I want to create a Grafana alert if the value of `my-custom-metric` is constant for a long time (say 1 hour). How will the query for this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make use of the [CHANGES](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#changes) prometheus function:

```
changes(my-custom-metric[1h]) == 0
```

changes() function calculates the number of times the value of my-custom-metric has changed over the past hour. The changes() function returns the number of times the value has changed within the given time range, so if the value has remained constant, the result will be 0. The == 0 comparison at the end of the query checks if the number of changes is equal to 0, which means the value has remained constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't find my custom metric in the list of metrics while trying to create the alert. Any idea why it might be?

Comment: Thats a different question altogether, if you can provide additional details in a new question I will take a look. If this answered your question can you please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus query to check if the value of the metric is the same as 1 hour ago:

```
my-custom-metric == my-custom-metric offset 1h
```

If there is a possibility that your metric could become the same as 1 hour ago after a reset, you could use

```
increase(my-custom-metric[2m]) == 0
```

and set `for` 1h.